# How to name the template for the node of a specific view?

Tags: views

Hello I find difficult to name the node of a view.

I created HTML-list view (but can be grid, table, unformatted etc) named topic.

I can theme its whole page using:
views-view-list--topic.tpl.php

But I need a template just for the item in the list:

```
<li class="topix">teaser here...</li>
```

How do I name the template? I have hundreds suggestions in View>Theme:Information but all they work either for all view or on particular fields.

I tried the most eligible: node-view--topic.tpl.php (this won't work)/ views-view-list--topic.tpl.php (this one works but for all page)

Many thanks

Comment: Please add the version of Drupal to your question.

Comment: How much theming are you looking to do? If you want to alter the `<li>` items you should be using a version of views-view-list.tpl.php